cudaMemcpyFromSymbol and different compilation units
I'm trying to get a pointer to a Cuda function so I can pass it to a Cuda kernel.
I created a helper function GetDeviceSymbolAddress which gets the device symbol by const reference and returns its value. In my case, it should return the function pointer.
I then pass the function pointer to a Cuda kernel and call it.
However, I noticed that if the Cuda kernel is defined in a different compilation (in a different .cu file), the address that the GetDeviceSymbolAddress returns is different (and probably invalid) and the kernel function fails to call it.
Here is an example:
test.chu:
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <iostream>

#define SWITCH 1

using pfloat__fn_pvoid = float* (*)(const void*);

// Test and log Cuda errors
#define CUDA_CHECK(err)                                     \
  do {                                                      \
    auto e = err; /* err might be a function call */        \
    if (e != cudaSuccess) {                                 \
      std::cout << "CUDA ERROR: " << cudaGetErrorString(e); \
      abort();                                              \
    }                                                       \
  } while (0)

template <typename T>
T GetDeviceSymbolAddress(const T& dvc_symbol) {
  T hst_symbol{};
  CUDA_CHECK(cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&hst_symbol, dvc_symbol, sizeof(T)));
  std::cout << (void*)hst_symbol << std::endl;
  return hst_symbol;
}

void RunTest(pfloat__fn_pvoid result_fn);

#endif /* TEST_H */

test.cu:
#include "test.cuh"

#ifdef SWITCH

__global__ void Test(pfloat__fn_pvoid fn) {
  fn(nullptr);
}

void RunTest(pfloat__fn_pvoid fn) {
  Test<<<1, 1>>>(fn);
  CUDA_CHECK(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
}

#endif

test1.cu:
#include "test.cuh"

__device__ float* Foo(const void* data) {
  return nullptr;
}

__device__ pfloat__fn_pvoid pFoo = Foo;

#ifndef SWITCH

__global__ void Test(pfloat__fn_pvoid fn) {
  fn(nullptr);
}

void RunTest(pfloat__fn_pvoid fn) {
  Test<<<1, 1>>>(fn);
  CUDA_CHECK(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
}
#endif

int main() {
  RunTest(GetDeviceSymbolAddress(pFoo));
  return 0;
}

The location of the kernel function can be switch between the two compilation units by def/undef SWITCH
Why does it matter in which compilation unit the kernel is defined?
Does it matter in which compilation unit the cudaMemcpyFromSymbol is called?

It is not the same question as the one in "Passing CUDA function pointers with libraries"

It's the same answer. If you compile with the same commands Robert shows in his answer (minus the obsolete -arch setting), it will work. If not, please [edit] the question to include the compile commands
